EC2 instances not attaching/assigning to my cluster and terminating immediately with " DryRun flag is set" in cloudtrail RunInstance logs
>  "eventName": "RunInstances",
>     "awsRegion": "ap-south-1",
>     "sourceIPAddress": "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
>     "userAgent": "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
>     "errorCode": "Client.DryRunOperation",
>     "errorMessage": "Request would have succeeded, but DryRun flag is set."

Found this error in cloudtrail logs under RunInstance.

The CloudTrail thing you found does not seem like it could be related to the EC2 registration with ECS issue. The CloudTrail log says "we tested to see if we had permission to create an EC2 instance, but we didn't actually create one". If you are seeing instances creating and then terminating, then the instances are actually being created, so the dry run RunInstances command couldn't have been used for those.

It used to work before but now it isnt. Moreover i couldnt find the dryrun operation. need help on how to remove the this flag.
